# How to install custom chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I want to install custom chaincode on my hyperledger fabric channel. I put my chaincode.go file besides of my .yaml files .when I run this command :

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
```

I got this error:

> Error: error getting chaincode code mycc: path to chaincode does not
>   exist: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go

I do not know where is `opt/gopath` or how to address the chaincode.go file?
please help me

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your network (if you are using the first-network template), you bring up a container 'CLI', you can find it in docker-compose-cli.yaml

This container is used to operate on the differents nodes of the architecture.

You need to create a volume who match your chaincode path like so

[image]

Then, when the container 'cli' goes up, you can enter into it with

```
docker exec -it cli bash
```

Now you can navigate to your path and see your chaincode directory.

And do your command :

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p path/define/in/your/volume/section/to/your/chaincode
```